# How to configure Chromium's Java plugin so it uses an existing JDK in the machine

Tags: java, linux, jdk

This exact same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962048/how-to-configure-chromes-java-plugin-so-it-uses-an-existing-jdk-in-the-machine), but the OP was asking in regard to a Windows system.  I am running [Linux Mint 14 "Nadia" - KDE (64-bit)](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=126).  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508769/288341) @Kalyan Akella provided to that question should work for me, but it does not.

Here are the details of my situation:

1. To stay consistent with my development team I need to use the 32 bit version of jdk-6u18, so I have downloaded `jdk-6u18-linux-i586.bin`.
2. Before installing the JDK I have completely removed all (and I mean all) Java related packages, including all `OpenJava` packages.  I have tried leaving `java-common` installed, but it doesn't make a difference.
3. To install a Java 32 bit JDK on my 64 bit OS I had to install `ia32-libs` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9394188/288341).
4. I have tried installing the previously mentioned JDK in the following directories...

   ```
   /usr/local  
   /usr/lib  
   /usr/java
   ```
5. I set my `JAVA_HOME` variable accordingly depending on where I have installed the JDK at (i.e. the path to the `jdk1.6.0_18` directory).  I add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to my path.  I have also set the (unneeded?) `JRE_HOME` variable to `$JAVA_HOME/jre`.

   When I run `set` all variables display as I would expect them to.  In the `jdk1.6.0_18` directory I have also tried setting permissions recursively to `755` just to make sure my problem was not a permissions error.  With all of these configurations everything Java related seems to work fine except the browser plugin.
6. I have tried setting the `MOZILLA_HOME` variable to `~/.mozilla` and `$HOME/.mozilla`.  Both seem to accomplish the same thing and display as I would expect them to when I run `set`.
7. I understand that Chrome, Chromium, and Firefox require a link to `libnpjp2.so` in a `plugins` directory for Java to work in those browsers.  I have created the link using `sudo ln -s` in the following directories...

   ```
   ~/.mozilla/plugins
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins
   /usr/lib/firefox/plugins
   ```

   ... and have also attempted to set the permissions of the link to `755`, all to no avail.

   I have run out of ideas, and I really don't want to have the dual Java installations.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Don’t use Java 6.18. It is old, buggy, and insecure. If you absolutely must use Java 6, use the last vesrion (6.43). It is still old, buggy, insecure and unsupported, but at least not as much as the one you are trying to use.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't that easy.  My organization uses 6.18 so that is what I need to use as well.

Comment: Java 6.43 is 100% compatible with 6.18.

Comment: @kinokijuf It isn't about compatibility, it is about matching development and production environments as exactly as possible, bugs and all.  If 6.43 was exactly like 6.18 then there would not have been a need for 6.43 :-)

Comment: You shouldn’t use 6.18 in a production environment. There are lots of exploits for it in the wild.